Unable to get Intellisense working on coder code-server
I'm unable to get Intellisense functions to work, such as auto complete, with various languages. I've tried with R and Julia, but I'll focus on R in the example. We are running rhel 8.10 and have setup the code-server version of vscode provided by coder.  Environments are managed through anaconda.
For R I have done the following steps:

Created a conda environment
Install the "languageserver" package to the environment via CRAN (version 0.3.16).
Install the R extension from REditorSupport
Install other R packages (e.g. dbscan, tidyverse)
Created an R file similar to the hdbscan vignette

There is no auto-complete as I would expect, and after a few minutes the R language server fails with this error:

R Language Server (-1) started
Error Client R Language Server: connection is erroring
Server initialization failed.  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed.
R Language Server client: couldn't create connection to server

I have tried:

Reinstalling extensions
Recreating anaconda environments

Nothing seems to be working for R.  I have Pyright installed for Python which seems to be working, minus the syntax highlighting.
